Index rebuild on a GUID clustered index?
I have a large table with the clustered index on a GUID (uniqueidentifier) column. So the rows are not in any kind of logical order, they are physically sorted by this random-generated ID.
Does an index rebuild make any sense on such a table? Or can I just skip it and only do Stats Update? This is for SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition.
The rows would not be in any (date, incremental ID, etc) order anyway, they would come in a chaotic order after each other, even after an index rebuild.
I am looking if an index rebuild makes sense in such a case at all.

If you "have" to have your clustered index on a uniqueidentifier at least make sure you are using NEWSEQUENTIALID. If you can't, then that column really should not be the CI.

"Does x make sense" can only be answered in the context of "what is the desired outcome?". Is this a static table and you're trying to save space? Are you somehow trying to get better performance? Something else?


Does an index rebuild make any sense on such a table? Or can I just skip it and only do Stats Update?

Skip it.  The random GUIDs will cause page splits on most inserts, but the steady state of that index will be to maintain ~60% free space.
If you rebuild with no fill factor, then you will generate a ton of page splits after the rebuild.  And if you rebuild with a fill factor, you just rewrite the table for no good reason.
Note that if you generate the values with newsequentialid you won't have all the page splits and empty space.


You're missing the incidence of other DML operations (namely UPDATE and DELETE, which not necessarily use the primary key in the WHERE clause). 2 "If you rebuild with no fill factor" Then, the advice should be "if you decide to rebuild the index, then you should specify the fill factor".

